# php function to determine how much of the total time was at night

Tags: php

I have two variables, a start hour and an end hour.

I need to determine which part of that is between 06:00 and 19:00 (morning time)
or how long the time between them is at night (19:00 to 06:00)?

Comment: Did you try to use the DateTime class of PHP ? http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$sunset = date_sunset(strtotime('2013-02-26 noon'), $timezone, SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP);
$sunrise = date_sunrise(strtotime('2013-02-27 noon'), $timezone, SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP);
```

This way you should get the timestamps for the sunset and sunrise. See [`date_sunrise()`'](http://php.net/date-sunrise) and [`date_sunset()`](http://php.net/date-sunset) for details of the arguments, because your probably need further information for useful values (compare sunset in cairo and in helsinki ;)).

Now you should be able to find the time periods, which are in the night, if you follow some rules

- Every night period between start and end *without* taking care about the time (just assume "noon" for example)
- Remove from the night periods of

  - The start date: If start is within "night", The difference between sunset and start
  - The end date: If end is within "night", The difference between end and sunrise

Comment: Good Stuff, I completely forgot about those two functions. up vote  =]

Comment: @Supplement I fear it is completely _not_ what the OP is looking for, but because simply "between 22:00 to 6:00" is a little bit boring, I thought I could be interesting for others :D